# Categorically expressed property in $\textbf{Set}$ for $P(A)=\{17\}$

Tags: category-theory

I'm reading Fokkinga's [*Gentle Introduction to Category Theory*](http://wwwhome.ewi.utwente.nl/~fokkinga/mmf92b.pdf), of which page 12 asks to give *categorically expressed properties* (i.e., using the language of basic CT and existensial qualifiers) in $\textbf{Set}$ for, among others:

- $P(A) \quad\equiv\quad A = \{17\}$
- $P(A) \quad\equiv\quad A$ is a singleton set.

Am I correct in thinking that the former is impossible -- namely because you can't "look inside" an object using only category theory tools? Whereas for the second, $A$ is a singleton set *iff* for all $X$ in $\textbf{Set}$ there is only one arrow $X \to A$?

(The rest of the mini-exercise is rather confusing, as well. I'd be forever grateful if someone could supply an "answer sheet" for when I get stuck!)

Comment: It mostly depends on what axioms for the category of sets are used.

Comment: You're right about both.

Comment: @OmarAntolín-Camarena: Cool. Thanks!

Comment: A way to formalize the "can't look inside" intuition is to say that *categorically expressed properties* are preserved under isomorphism, i.e., if an object has such a property so do all isomorphic objects.

Comment: I agree that it is probably an exercise in thinking categorically, i.e., making isomorphic things essentially the same. In this case, both $\{17\}$ and any singleton set are terminal objects in $\mathbf{Set}$, so they are isomorphic (both are the limit of the empty diagram). And using just the axioms of category theory, you can't tell one from the other.